# SQL Query combine multiple results or Join tables

Tags: sql-server, database, join, sql-server-2012

I have the Following tables

> Disposition Table

```
  Dis_ID | OfferID  |  RequestID
------------------------------------
 34564   | 123       |    9
 77456   | 123       |    8
 25252   | 124       |    7
 46464   | 125       |    10
 36464   | 125       |    6
 35353   | 125       |    5
```

> Request Table

```
  RequestID | AccountNum | 
---------------------------
 5          | 548543      |   
 6          | 548543      |
 7          | 684567      |  
 8          | 684567      |  
 9          | 684567      | 
10          | 548543      | 
11          | 684567      |
```

> Rank Table

```
 RankID | OfferId  |  RequestID | Score
-------------------------------------------
 34564   | 123       |    11      |   1
 77456   | 124       |    11      |   2
 25252   | 125       |    11      |   3
```

Using the data above I need a query which would behave as follows given a  request number look at every record in the Rank Table in this example we have 3 (123, 124, & 125). return the OfferId that appears the fewest times in the Disposition table for this joined account number. in this example offerId 123 appears twice for this account number, offerId 124 appears once and offerId 125 doesn't appears at all for this account number. So offerId 125 should be returned. The offerId which exist in the Rank Table with the fewest appearances in the Disposition table should always be returned unless they are all the same then return the offerId with the lowest value in the Score field. for example if none of the offerIDs appeared in the Dispostion table offerId 123 would return since its Score value is 1.

> Resulting table would look something like this

```
| OfferId   | Score | Dis_Occurrences 
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 123       |   1   |   2
| 124       |   2   |   1
| 125       |   3   |   0      <--Return this record
```

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT oRank.OfferId, oRank.Rank_Number, count(oRank.OfferId) AS NumDispositions
From Rank oRank
join Request req
on oRank.RequestId = req.RequestId
join Disposition dis 
on oRank.OfferId = dis.OfferId
where req.Customer_Account_Number = 684567 and req.RequestId = 11 and oRank.OfferId = dis.OfferId
group by oRank.Rank_Number, oRank.OfferId
order by NumDispositions, oRank.Rank_Number
```

> My incorrect Resulting table looks like this

```
| OfferId   | Score | Dis_Occurrences 
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 123       |   1   |   2
| 124       |   2   |   1
| 125       |   3   |   3
```

It is counting the total number of times the offerId appears in the Disposition Table

Comment: Sql server or mysql?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I am using MicrosoftSQL.

Comment: How should the Rank and Disposition tables be joined? In your example query you join them by RequestID, but in the sample data you posted there are no RequestIDs in common between them. Maybe you meant to join by OfferID instead?

Comment: @beercohol You are completely correct I've updated my Query different  results but still incorrect thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT - based on author's comments, here's another version:**

Example in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3f99/1/0

```
with RankReqMap as (
    select rnk.OfferId, rnk.Score, reqAcct.AccountNum, reqReq.RequestID
    from           [Rank]  rnk
         left join Request reqAcct on reqAcct.RequestID = rnk.RequestID
         left join Request reqReq  on reqReq.AccountNum = reqAcct.AccountNum

    where rnk.RequestID = 11 -- Put your RequestId filter here
)
select oRank.OfferId
      ,oRank.Score
      ,count(dis.RequestID) as NumDispositions
from           RankReqMap  oRank
     left join Disposition dis on dis.OfferID   = oRank.OfferId
                              and dis.RequestID = oRank.RequestID
group by oRank.OfferId  , oRank.Score
order by NumDispositions, oRank.Score;
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

Example in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/770a8/1/0

This query makes the assumption that you're joining Disposition to Rank based on OfferID, since the RequestIDs for those tables in your example data don't match up. You may have to tweak depending on your needs, but something like the query below should get you the record you're looking for:

```
-- Gather base data
with RankData as (
    select rnk.RankID
          ,rnk.OfferID
          ,rnk.RequestID
          ,rnk.Score
          ,Dis_Occurrences = count(dis.OfferID)
    from           dbo.[Rank]      rnk
         left join dbo.Disposition dis on dis.OfferID   = rnk.OfferId
         left join dbo.Request     req on req.RequestID = rnk.RequestID
    group by rnk.RankID, rnk.OfferID, rnk.RequestID, rnk.Score
)
-- Rank count of Dis_Occurrences, taking lowest score into account as a tie breaker
, DispRanking as (
    select rdt.*, Dis_Rank = row_number() over (order by Dis_Occurrences asc, rdt.Score asc)
    from RankData rdt
)
-- Return only the value with the highest ranking
select * from DispRanking where Dis_Rank = 1
```

Note also that if you convert the second CTE into a naked SELECT and remove the SELECT statement at the end, you can see all of the records and how they get ranked by the row_number() function:

```
-- Gather base data
with RankData as (
    select rnk.RankID
          ,rnk.OfferID
          ,rnk.RequestID
          ,rnk.Score
          ,Dis_Occurrences = count(dis.OfferID)
    from          dbo.[Rank]      rnk
        left join dbo.Disposition dis on dis.OfferID   = rnk.OfferId
        left join dbo.Request     req on req.RequestID = rnk.RequestID
    group by rnk.RankID, rnk.OfferID, rnk.RequestID, rnk.Score
)
-- Output all values, with rankings
select rdt.*, Dis_Rank = row_number() over (order by Dis_Occurrences asc, rdt.Score asc)
from RankData rdt
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response!!! Your assumption is correct offerId's much be whats joined on ive updated my query quite a bit. I think I confused everyone with my first query being so botched. I have to use a provided RequestID This will tell me which records to pull from the Rank table. I also have to use the Account number to indirectly find the list of disposition records that have RequestId's which map back to the provided account number in the Request table. I tried your solution but i got incorrect results it actually didnt find any of the matching offers in Rank table with Disposition table

Comment: Can you clarify your source tables? In the query you provided, you're referencing oRank.Rank_Number, which doesn't appear anywhere in your data. I'm also assuming that Customer_Account_Number from Request should be AccountNum based on your data...

Comment: Made a couple of assumptions and posted an updated version that displays your zero value at the top. See if that one works for you.

Comment: embarrassingly enough I was stuck on this for a week before I posted thanks a ton man!!!. Off topic do you have any SQL resources you would recommend

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use window function for this:

```
;with disp as(select offerid, count(*) as ocount 
              from dispositions group by offerid),
rnk as(select r.offerid, 
              row_number() over(partition by r.requestid 
                                order by isnull(d.ocount, 0), r.score) rn 
       from ranks r
       left join disp d on r.offerid = d.offerid)
select * from rnk where rn = 1
```